# Serial dispatch queue using Executors in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a need to manage a large number of serial dispatch queues in Java. There are a number of engine modules that are required to each manage their own run loop (some of them may finish very quickly, others may block for a long period of time). The jobs submitted to each engine must be run in order.

Ideally, each engine would have a single thread pool that scales between 0 and 1 thread, making the ExecutorService both serial, and not incredibly resource heavy in the event that there are hundreds of them, but only a few are seeing activity.

However, when I tried using *either*:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 1, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
```

or

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
```

I find that when a second job is submitted (if the first job is still running) a `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown, I assume because I have one thread to run two jobs, and the executor doesn't like that.

I could implement this with my own queue, and start/stop/dispose of my own `Thread` instance on demand, but it seems like this is something that a `0<=n<=1` Executor could do.

Is there an `Executors.` method (or implementation of Executor) that will create a cached thread pool, with one at most, that allows it to also expire and die if there are no jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular issue comes from the use of a [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html#SynchronousQueue--), as the documentation mentions:

> A synchronous queue does not have any internal capacity, not even a capacity of one.

So if you replace this by a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), it actually works.

What you can use however, regarding *Executors*, is a [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) as it uses at top one thread to execute task.

A simple example:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    TestThread t1 = new TestThread(1);
    TestThread t2 = new TestThread(2);
    executor.submit(t1);
    Future<?> f2 = executor.submit(t2);
    try {
        f2.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ThreadPoolExecutor tt = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executor;
    System.out.println(tt.getActiveCount()); //ensuring that there is no active threads in the pool after last thread terminates
}

public static class TestThread implements Runnable{
    private int id;

    public TestThread(int num){
        id = num;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running thread: " + id);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("After sleeping thread " + id);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Gives the output expected:

```
running thread: 1
After sleeping thread 1
running thread: 2
After sleeping thread 2
0
```

There is no active thread after the last one terminated.